# Drawable is blank in layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-drawable

I have a `Drawable` that I am trying to set as an icon for the error message of an `EditText`.

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.question_mark);
EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pan_card_num);
editText.setError("Hello",drawable);
```

However, when I do the above, it ends up looking blank like this:

[image]

That is, the error message `Hello` is displayed, but the icon is not. It might be important to mention that the drawable `R.drawable.question_mark` is a `png` file in the `drawable` folders.

Comment: from the docs : The drawable must already have had Drawable.setBounds set on it.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see is that the Business PANCard textfield is overlaying over the question mark image. I would make the `textView` smaller, to leave space for the image to be shown.

Comment: That's not possible, because `EditText#setError`places the image on top. of the Text View, within its bounds. If I took out the `drawable` parameter from the method, it would display the default "exclamation mark" image on top. I'm just trying to replace that image, which is definitely on top of the text view. In fact, if I tap the blank spot, the message `hello` displays. If it was behind the `TextView` that wouldn't be possible.